# Why must I use a variable to get values from a Python generator?

Tags: python, generator

Why must I use a variable to obtain next() values from a Python generator?

```
    def my_gen():
    i = 0
    while i < 4:
         yield 2 * i
         i += 1

#p = my_gen()
#for i in range(4):
#    print(next(p))

##for i in range(4):
##    print(next(my_gen()))
```

In the above, the  #  block works, while the  ##  block returns 4 copies of the first "yield."

Comment: `my_gen()` creates a new generator. That is, `next(p)` isn't equivalent to just calling `my_gen()` repeatedly.

Comment: you can just use the generator: `print(*my_gen())`    
`0 2 4 6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(next(my_gen()))
```

Each time this runs, you're calling `next()` on a separate (and brand-new) generator returned by `my_gen()`.

If you want to call `next()` on the same generator more than once, you'll need some way to keep that generator around for long enough to reuse it.

Comment: python's naming of generators / iterators / crazy a** functions is a little broken. It adds great functionality, but the way many of them are explained only confuses people

Comment: @aaron can you explain why they are broken?

Comment: @PaulRooney many people refer to generators, iterators, and coroutines (async functions, etc.) interchangably. There are technically individual separate definitions, but the subtle differences can easily confuse those who haven't poked around in the cPython source to learn what's actually happening.. This is one aspect I prefer about Lua over python in that there are functions and co-routines and nothing else. (but that's a little bit apples to oranges)

Answer (score 1):

just gonna add my $0.02...

this may help clear up some misconceptions:

```
def function_that_creates_a_generator(n):
    while n>0:
        yield n
        n - 1

# this
for x in function_that_creates_a_generator(5):
    print(x)

#is almost exactly the same as this
generator = function_that_creates_a_generator(5)
while True:
    try:
        x = generator.next() #same as: x = next(generator)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print(x)
```

For loops are really just a prettier way of writing a while loop that continually asks an iterable object for its next element. when you ask an iterable for another object and it has none, it will raise a `StopIteration` exception that is automatically caught in for loops; signaling a break from the loop. In the while loop we simply break these things out individually instead of having them hidden by the interpreter.